# If $X$ and $Y$ are lognormal and $E[\ln X - \ln Y]=k$, what can we say about $E[X-Y]$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Question in the title. Is there a simple relationship between a difference in the means of normal random variables underlying two lognormal random variables and the difference in the means between the lognormal variables themselves?

Comment: You are asking if one can deduce the value of $E(e^{\mu+\sigma Z}-e^{\nu+\tau Z})=e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2}-e^{\nu+\tau^2/2}$, where $Z$ is standard normal, from the value of $\mu-\nu$. Well, already $e^{\mu}-e^{\nu}$ cannot be deduced from the value of $\mu-\nu$, hence...

Comment: you can say sth about their sum.

Comment: If you give the parameters of X and Y, then we can say a lot.

Comment: @crf To react to the critics in my comment by, instead of addressing them, offering a bounty with the reason that "This question has not received enough attention" is odd.

Comment: @Did I would have accepted your answer if it was an answer. I wasn't reacting to the critics of your comment